# HTML5 constraint-validation fails when data is pre-filled

Tags: html, validation

I'm currently struggeling with HTML5 constraint validation.

Given this simple form:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="comeGetSome" value="" required="required" maxlength="10" /><br />      
    <input type="submit" value="Send me" />
</form>
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN6R3PLQ7A3D

It will not submit as long as there is a value given for `comeGetSome` which is fine.

However, when setting the value to something longer than 10 characters, the form will submit just fine.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="comeGetSome" value="This is way too long" required="required" maxlength="10" /><br />      
    <input type="submit" value="Send me" />
</form>
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN6R4H30WQI2

The problem occurs when I have something I need to edit and fields have to be prefilled with data thay may fail (as of requirements have been changed).
It should not allow the user to submit the data (even if stored as valid before) until the data is changed to be valid.

Why is the `required` validation handled, but `maxlength` is not? Are there any known workarounds?

Comment: This issue discussed here :https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/10/17/maxlength-constraint-validation-oddities/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maxlength` seems only to work after some changes are done on the content of the `<input>` element. You can also use `pattern` to define the maxlength of the `<input>`:

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="comeGetSome" value="This is way too long" required="required" pattern=".{1,10}" /><br />      
    <input type="submit" value="Send me" />
</form>
```

> The constraint is evaluated only when the value of the attribute has been changed.
> **source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-maxlength
>
> **Constraint validation:** If an element has a maximum allowed value length, its dirty value flag is true, its value was last changed by a user edit (as opposed to a change made by a script), and the JavaScript string length of the element's API value is greater than the element's maximum allowed value length, then the element is suffering from being too long.
> **source:** https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-maxlength